Application Roles are in my on-behalf-of flow created bearer token
I'm working on implementing the on-behalf-of flow in one of my services that is acting somewhat as a middleware/backend-for-frontend service and needs to invoke a backend API with the user it's context.
Currently, the backend is using Application Roles to perform authorization on the different endpoints. We have a User and an Admin role defined (we use Entra ID).
For the sample I'm creating I own both of the services (integrating- and backend service).
To pass along the user context, I figured to use the on-behalf-of flow. MS Learn has some details on it and states the following:

For the middle-tier service to make authenticated requests to the downstream service, it needs to secure an access token from the Microsoft identity platform. It only uses delegated scopes and not application roles. Roles remain attached to the principal (the user) and never to the application operating on the user's behalf. This occurs to prevent the user gaining permission to resources they shouldn't have access to.

This sounds to me like Application Roles will NOT be added to the token generated via the OBO flow.
However, I do see the Application Roles pop-up in the token.
I use the following code:
private readonly IAuthorizationHeaderProvider _authorizationHeaderProvider;

public MyController(
    IAuthorizationHeaderProvider authorizationHeaderProvider
)
{
    this._authorizationHeaderProvider = authorizationHeaderProvider;
}

[HttpGet("WeatherForecastWithWeatherUserScope", Name = "GetWeatherForecastWithWeatherUserScope")]
public async Task<ApiResponse> GetWithUserScope()
{
    var accessToken = await this._authorizationHeaderProvider.CreateAuthorizationHeaderForUserAsync(new[] { "api://2a3f9f34-0ee2-4fe7-8b37-e8233c51e620/WeatherUser" });
    accessToken = accessToken.Replace("Bearer ", "");
    var backendDetails = await GetBackendDetails(accessToken, "/WeatherForecast/WithUserScope/");

    var integrationServiceDetails = new IntegrationServiceCallDetails(
        HttpContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.First()!,
        username);

    return new ApiResponse(integrationServiceDetails, backendDetails);
}

And the token, accessToken, has the following contents:
{
  // Removed some properties for brevity
  "aud": "2a3f9f34-0ee2-4fe7-8b37-e8233c51e620",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/15a8d236-9fcd-4d34-a6d9-f09eb524ed78/v2.0",
  "name": "Jan_V",
  "oid": "bf63f1b5-6c1f-489c-8d70-e47a82deaa69",
  "preferred_username": "my@mail.com",
  "roles": [
    "Admin"
  ],
  "scp": "user_impersonation WeatherAdmin WeatherUser",
  "tid": "15a8d236-9fcd-4d34-a6d9-f09eb524ed78",
  "ver": "2.0"
}

As you can see in the above exerpt, my Application Role Admin is right there in the token.
I'm glad it's there, because the backend service is using this for authorization, but I'm a bit amazed to see it. Am I misunderstanding the above quote, or is something else going on over here?
Note: The managed identity assigned to the integrating service does NOT have any roles assigned.

I understand what you mean and this phrase is particularly interesting: This occurs to prevent the user gaining permission to resources they shouldn't have access to.  I would expect that to say This occurs to prevent the application gaining permission to resources they shouldn't have access to. as a logical conclusion. But perhaps they meant to say that the impersonating user does not inherit the roles.

There are a couple of specifications related to token exchange. Microsoft's on behalf of flow is closer to the former but also enables changes to scopes like the latter:

RFC 7523 - JWT Authorization Grants
RFC 8793 - Token Exchange

Regardless of the implementation, the goal is to get a new access token with adjusted scopes, while securely maintaining the user identity and other user claims in the new access token.
SCOPES CONTAIN CLAIMS
Usually in OAuth you design scopes to contain claims. Consider a client with the following scopes so that 3 custom claims exist in the original access token:

Orders scope contains claims CustomerId and Role
Payments scope contains claims CustomerId and CreditRating

In Entra ID you would configure such claims under the Attributes and Claims settings for each API / resource server.
If I used the on behalf of flow to remove the Orders scope I would want to remove the Role claim. If I maintained the scope I would also maintain its claims. This might be the default Entra ID behaviour that you are seeing, and something you could verify.
The default claims behaviour may vary across authorization servers since specifications leave some behaviour open. Ultimately, the claims you issue in the final token should be up to you. Some implementations may give you more control over the final claims than others.
